# sharepoint cms development

Tags: sharepoint

i am an asp.net (C#) developer and have been devloping cms for quite a while now

now i need to develop cms in sharepoint...can u plz suggest me steps , methods or tutorials or step by step procedure (free links) for developing cms in sharepoint

Plz help

Comment: You don't have to make 2 exactly same questions. You can modify existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to develop a CMS in SharePoint.. it comes with one out of the box!

That said, try [Andrew Connells](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/) website. He's also written [a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470224754) about doing CMS stuff with MOSS.